# How to pass output buffer to shared object

Tags: python-2.7

Disclaimer: I am completely new to Python and might ask some obvious seeming questions...

I have wrapped some shared libraries in Python (2.7) which are compiled from C.

Function definitions use int8_t * pointers as buffers to be populated by the shared object (in this case a device driver) - i wrapped these as ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int8).

How do I create and pass an object of this type in Python, such that the driver can write to it?

In this specific case, I'm pretty sure the driver is looking to pass back a CSV string into the buffer - if that helps.

I have been playing around with buffer, bytearray, ctypes.create_string_buffer(), but can't seem to end up with any object in a useful format.

Edited with my latest stumblings around Python...

Here's some more info on what I'm trying to do / what's going wrong.

Test code:

```
from PicoPt104 import *
import ctypes

stringbuffer=ctypes.create_string_buffer(1000)
bufferpointer=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int8)(stringbuffer)
length=ctypes.c_uint32(len(stringbuffer))
lengthpointer=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32)(ctypes.c_uint32(ctypes.addressof(length)))

myWrapper.myWrappedFunction(bufferpointer,lengthpointer,1)
```

This produces a segmentation fault (perhaps unsurprisingly with the amount of casting I am doing here!).  I'm sure there's a simpler way to accomplish what must be a fairly common use (calling some compiled C from Python).

The original .h file had a definition like this:

```
uint32_t OriginalCFunction (int8_t *details, uint32_t *length, int type);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I'm pretty sure that the Test code I added in my edit was the correct solution - specifically this part:

```
stringbuffer=ctypes.create_string_buffer(1000)
bufferpointer=ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int8)(stringbuffer)
```

for creating an output buffer which could be passed to & written by the underlying C function.  I ended up wrapping the C function in more C so that I could provide arguments exactly as expected in a language I was familiar with.  When the new C wrapper was wrapped for Python & executed, the same memory fault was produced.  Debug indicated that the memory fault was occurring in the shared library (am doing some cross development with dubiously-compatible libraries...).

Anyway, thought I should post back here!